# finding object size from speed and change in pixel width

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, camera, physics, raspberry-pi2

This is very likely a duplicate question but I could not find what I was looking for.

I'm trying to determine the size of an object from the speed of the object(actually the camera is moving but I would guess that it calculates the same), and a change in pixel width . Any help would be appreciated.

speed is roughly 2 m/s

change in pixel width is roughly 3 pixels/frame

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was:

```
X width(meters) = ((speed * focal length) / change in pixel width)^.5
```